# Recreating the starbucks website, cant get text and images to be on same line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to recreate the html/css portion of the Starbucks website. Things are going great, the issue I am having however is that I cannot get my text on the same line as the image files. The official Starbucks website (https://www.starbucks.com/) has the text description and the image on the same line. What am I missing in my code? If this can be solved with flexbox properties, that would be great. Thanks.

```css
html {
  font-family: noto sans jp, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  width: 500px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.header {
  background-color: rgb(221, 255, 247);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.star {
  background-color: rgb(226, 0, 0);
  color: white;
}

.drinks {
  background-color: rgb(226, 0, 0);
  color: white;
}

.cookie {
  background-color: rgb(0, 54, 24);
  color: white;
}

.card {
  background-color: rgb(221, 255, 247);
  color: black;
}

.people {
  background-color: rgb(0, 54, 24);
  color: white;
}

.terms {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

table {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<main>
  <nav>
    <img>
    <ul>
      <li>Menu</li>
      <li>Rewards</li>
      <li>Gift Cards</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header class='header'>
    <p>We’re working hard to put the health and well-being of our partners and customers first in all that we do. Learn more</p>
  </header>
  <section class='star'>
    <img src='star.png' alt='star'>
    <h3>Wishing you the warmest Rewards</h3>
    <p>Starbucks® Rewards members can now pay any way they’d like in the app and collect Stars to redeem for free holiday faves. Positively jolly.*</p>
    <p class='button'>Get the app</p>
  </section>
  <section class='drinks'>
    <img src='drinks.png' alt='drinks'>
    <h1>HOLIDAY YOUR WAY</h1>
    <p>So many convenient ways to get your festive favorites.</p>
    <p class='button'>Explore seasonal drinks</p>
  </section>
  <section class='cookie'>
    <img src='cookie.png' alt='cookie'>
    <h1>BAKING SPIRITS BRIGHT</h1>
    <p>The new Cranberry Orange Scone: made with crème fraîche, dried cranberries, orange zest and a drizzle of vanilla icing.</p>
    <p>Order now</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>CARRY THE MERRY</h1>
  </section>
  <section class='card'>
    <img src='card.jpg' alt='card'>
    <h3>Earning 4,500 Bonus Stars is Super Starifying</h3>
    <p>$0 intro annual fee for your first year with the Starbucks® Rewards Visa® Card. Plus your Stars won’t expire—an exclusive Starbucks benefit for cardmembers. Now that’s Super Starifying.**</p>
    <p>Learn more</p>
  </section>
  <section class='people'>
    <img src='people.jpg' alt='people'>
    <h3>Fueling our democracy</h3>
    <p>See how our partners (employees) have been involved in civic engagement, making their voices heard and strengthening their communities.</p>
    <p>Read more</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class='terms'>
      *Starbucks Rewards benefits are available at participating Starbucks stores. Some restrictions apply. See Starbucks.com/terms
    </p>
    <p class='terms'>
      **Under the Starbucks Rewards Program, Stars earned do not expire as long as your Starbucks® Rewards Visa® Credit Card account is open. If your Starbucks® Rewards Visa® Credit Card account is closed for any reason, your Stars will expire six (6) months
      after the calendar month in which that account was closed. Chase credit cards are issued by Chase Bank USA, N.A. Deposit products are provided by JPMorgan Chase Bank, N.A. Member FDIC
    </p>
  </section>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>About Us</th>
        <th>Careers</th>
        <th>Social Impact</th>
        <th>For Business Partners</th>
        <th>Ways To Order</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Our Heritage</td>
        <td>Culture and Values</td>
        <td>Ethical Sourcing</td>
        <td>Landlord Support Center</td>
        <td>Order on the Web</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Our Coffee</td>
        <td>Inclusion, Diversity, and Equity</td>
        <td>Leading in Sustainability</td>
        <td>Supplies</td>
        <td>Downoad the App</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Stories and News</td>
        <td>College Achievement Plan</td>
        <td>Strengthening Communities</td>
        <td>Corporate Gift Card Sales</td>
        <td>Delivery</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Investor Relations</td>
        <td>U.S. Careers</td>
        <td>Creating Opportunities</td>
        <td>Office and Footservice Coffee</td>
        <td>Google Assistant</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Policies and Standards</td>
        <td>International Careers</td>
        <td>Global Social Impact Report</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer Service</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li>Privacy Policy</li>
      <li>Terms of Use</li>
      <li>CA Supply Chain Act</li>
      <li>Submit Your Idea</li>
      <li>Cookie Preference</li>
    </ul>
    <p>© 2020 Starbucks Coffee Company. All rights reserved.</p>
  </footer>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text with tags `h1` and `p` must be wrapped in a container `div` ( `<div class="text_section">` ) for the correct distribution of the picture and text using the `flex` rule.

For the flex rule, I created a selector:

```
main section:not(:last-of-type) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

`:not(:last-of-type)` - this means that the rule will apply to all specified containers except the last one. Since the latter is not the `section` with the picture in your example.

Was it necessary?

```css
html {
  font-family: noto sans jp, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

main {

}

main section:not(:last-of-type) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.text_section {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 500px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.header {
  background-color: rgb(221, 255, 247);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.star {
  background-color: rgb(226, 0, 0);
  color: white;
}

.drinks {
  background-color: rgb(226, 0, 0);
  color: white;
}

.cookie {
  background-color: rgb(0, 54, 24);
  color: white;
}

.card {
  background-color: rgb(221, 255, 247);
  color: black;
}

.people {
  background-color: rgb(0, 54, 24);
  color: white;
}

.terms {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

table {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<main>
  <nav>
    <img>
    <ul>
      <li>Menu</li>
      <li>Rewards</li>
      <li>Gift Cards</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <header class='header'>
    <p>We’re working hard to put the health and well-being of our partners and customers first in all that we do. Learn more</p>
  </header>
  <section class='star'>
    <img src='https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg' alt='star'>
    <div class="text_section">
    <h3>Wishing you the warmest Rewards</h3>
    <p>Starbucks® Rewards members can now pay any way they’d like in the app and collect Stars to redeem for free holiday faves. Positively jolly.*</p>
    <p class='button'>Get the app</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class='drinks'>
    <img src='https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg' alt='drinks'>
    <div class="text_section">
    <h1>HOLIDAY YOUR WAY</h1>
    <p>So many convenient ways to get your festive favorites.</p>
    <p class='button'>Explore seasonal drinks</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class='cookie'>
    <img src='https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg' alt='cookie'>
    <div class="text_section">
    <h1>BAKING SPIRITS BRIGHT</h1>
    <p>The new Cranberry Orange Scone: made with crème fraîche, dried cranberries, orange zest and a drizzle of vanilla icing.</p>
    <p>Order now</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>CARRY THE MERRY</h1>
  </section>
  <section class='card'>
    <img src='https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg' alt='card'>
    <div class="text_section">
    <h3>Earning 4,500 Bonus Stars is Super Starifying</h3>
    <p>$0 intro annual fee for your first year with the Starbucks® Rewards Visa® Card. Plus your Stars won’t expire—an exclusive Starbucks benefit for cardmembers. Now that’s Super Starifying.**</p>
    <p>Learn more</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class='people'>
    <img src='https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg' alt='people'>
    <div class="text_section">
    <h3>Fueling our democracy</h3>
    <p>See how our partners (employees) have been involved in civic engagement, making their voices heard and strengthening their communities.</p>
    <p>Read more</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class='terms'>
      *Starbucks Rewards benefits are available at participating Starbucks stores. Some restrictions apply. See Starbucks.com/terms
    </p>
    <p class='terms'>
      **Under the Starbucks Rewards Program, Stars earned do not expire as long as your Starbucks® Rewards Visa® Credit Card account is open. If your Starbucks® Rewards Visa® Credit Card account is closed for any reason, your Stars will expire six (6) months
      after the calendar month in which that account was closed. Chase credit cards are issued by Chase Bank USA, N.A. Deposit products are provided by JPMorgan Chase Bank, N.A. Member FDIC
    </p>
  </section>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>About Us</th>
        <th>Careers</th>
        <th>Social Impact</th>
        <th>For Business Partners</th>
        <th>Ways To Order</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Our Heritage</td>
        <td>Culture and Values</td>
        <td>Ethical Sourcing</td>
        <td>Landlord Support Center</td>
        <td>Order on the Web</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Our Coffee</td>
        <td>Inclusion, Diversity, and Equity</td>
        <td>Leading in Sustainability</td>
        <td>Supplies</td>
        <td>Downoad the App</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Stories and News</td>
        <td>College Achievement Plan</td>
        <td>Strengthening Communities</td>
        <td>Corporate Gift Card Sales</td>
        <td>Delivery</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Investor Relations</td>
        <td>U.S. Careers</td>
        <td>Creating Opportunities</td>
        <td>Office and Footservice Coffee</td>
        <td>Google Assistant</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Policies and Standards</td>
        <td>International Careers</td>
        <td>Global Social Impact Report</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Customer Service</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li>Privacy Policy</li>
      <li>Terms of Use</li>
      <li>CA Supply Chain Act</li>
      <li>Submit Your Idea</li>
      <li>Cookie Preference</li>
    </ul>
    <p>© 2020 Starbucks Coffee Company. All rights reserved.</p>
  </footer>

</main>
```

Comment: always glad to help